# Disparity between votes cast and electorate badge count

Tags: bug, badges, voting

Before I got the "Electorate" badge which is awarded for

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

I noticed that there is a difference between the vote count it shows and the "votes cast" counter on the profile. First I thought that it is because of the 25%, i.e. it only counts maximum 3 answer upvotes for every question upvote.

But now my friend has a similar problem and definitely has way more than 25% of the votes on questions. **Why this disparity?**

Comment: Did you wait 24 hours without casting any additional votes on questions, to see if it's a caching problem?

Comment: @DavidZ the difference on my friend's account is currently roughly 130 votes. It says 490 under cast votes and 360 in the electorate badge tracker. That is a difference of more than the daily vote limit, so i don't think it can be that. or maybe it can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you're referring to the count on the badge tracker in your profile page. The Electorate badge is awarded for 600 votes cast on questions, so the count on the tracker will reflect that (i.e. it will tell you the number of votes you've cast on questions), and this is clarified in the display if you click on the progress bar. On the other hand, on the statistics on the right hand side gives the 'total number of up and down votes cast' (as per the tooltip), i.e. all your votes on questions plus all your votes on answers.

[image]

The two numbers are obviously completely independent, and subject only to (total votes) ≥ (question votes).

As for the 25% thing, it works by preventing you from getting the badge if you have too many answer votes per question votes: thus, if at the time of your 600th question vote you have more than 1800 answer votes (i.e. you have 600 question votes, but <25% of your total votes is on questions) then you won't get the badge. If you then cast more question votes, slower than you cast answer votes, you'll get the badge when you have cast less than three answer votes per question vote.

Comment: oh ok, essentially i misread the badge description. thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah, I see how it sorta kinda lends itself to a misunderstanding.